# Is there a way to merge strokes in grease pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil

I can't find a way to reliably merge two filled strokes on a grease pencil layer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I try to join two overlapping filled in strokes I get some pretty messed up results.

[image]

What I'd really like is some method to create a new filled in stroke like what I photoshopped below.

[image]

I've tried several different ways including closing the objects, dissolving certain vertices, trying to merge certain vertices, but will little luck. What am I missing? Does anyone know of a reliable means of doing this?

Comment: In Draw mode, the Cutter tool does exactly that.  You select at least 1 point using the Cutter tool, and it deletes all points until it reaches an intersecting stroke.  Only issue is sometimes it's hard to find a point because it's Draw mode, so you can't see the points (like you can in Edit mode).

Comment: Have you tried this? I've tried what you're saying and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What Blender version do you have?  Try it in Blender version 2.90, if you haven't.  I don't think the cutter tool worked well in 2.80 versions.

Comment: I'm using Blender 2.90.1. Do you think you could post a gif of you successfully doing this?